# How can I configure half dollar amounts to be displayed as $n.50 while whole dollar amounts display as $n?

Tags: 8, commerce

In drupal commerce, I have a product variation type with a price. In the 'manage display' area, in the 'format' section I have 'strip trailing zeroes' selected.

My prices are all either whole dollar amounts or half dollar amounts, for example $5.00 or $9.50. With 'strip trailing zeroes' selected, whole dollar amounts are displayed as expected: $5. However, half dollar amounts are displayed as $9.5.

How can I configure half dollar amounts to be displayed as $9.50 while whole dollar amounts display as $5?

Comment: Seems like you discovered a bug, unless they intended to work like this when there is only one zero which is odd if you ask me. You could report this as a bug and see what the maintainers say, or simply programmatically create your custom format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NoSssweat, much appreciated. I'll add a bug report to the issue queue on drupal.org and will investigate how to create a custom format.